# I get an typerror when plotting a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, join, plot, nan

I am just beginning to use pandas and struggling with very basic functions. I have a dataset that contains ticket information. I am able to do some basic computing like get count of total tickets, count of open tickets and also group these by labels like team. To make the output smooth, I joined two dataframes. There are over 31 teams and these can be categorized into smaller groups. When I simply try to find ticketcount by teams it works but if I plot the same I get an error which I cannot understand.

Here is the code:

**

```
incidentManagement=pd.merge(incidentManagement,groupTeam,on='Group',how='left')
incidentManagement.Team.fillna(value=pd.np.nan,inplace=True)
teamNames=incidentManagement['Team'].unique()
countTicketsbyTeam=incidentManagement.groupby('Team').TicketId.count()
plt.bar(teamNames,countTicketsbyTeam)
plt.show()
```

**

Here is the error I get

*raise TypeError("{val!r} is not a string".format(val=val))
TypeError: nan is not a string*

Comment: I did a print(teamNames) and can see nan. Not sure how to remedy this :                                   ['Service Desk' 'Ops' 'TechSol' 'Workday Project' 'PMO' 'Apps' 'SOLV' nan
 'Training' 'Sch' 'Craft Payroll']

Comment: My inexperience caused this. After seeing the nan show up with the print statement, I refactored the fillna line of code and it worked :                                                                            incidentManagement.Team.fillna(value='None',inplace=True)

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused due to missing values when I joined the 2 dataframes. Additionally i was incorrectly reimposing nan to missing values. I refactored the code to show 'None' instead of nan:

```
incidentManagement.Team.fillna(value='None',inplace=True)
```